# How to clarify a mixed-up situation addressing someone

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

I was talking to someone in a texting environment but someone else thought I was addressing him and I had no idea what could I have said to him to make myself clear and avoid a mixed-up situation.

I was wondering what I could say in such  a situation, I want to know what people use in everyday English?

Comment: Wait...what??? I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: "I was not addressing you, I was addressing X."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you texted the wrong person you should be apologetic, it's as if you said *something* to the wrong person.  Usually

> Sorry, that was meant for someone else.
>   Sorry, I didn't mean to send to to you.

Should work, though your errant text may have piqued the receiver's interest.

If you are very good friends with the person you sent in error, you might be able to get away with

> Wasn't meant for you *(mate)*.
>   Sorry, that wasn't for you.